Will this powershell script disable RDP with AWS ec2LaunchV2
I am creating a custom ami from an aws windows 2022 base ami. When I run sysprep with this command as the last item in my Powershell script. Will it disable rdp by default and a random Administrator password? Really poor documentation on how to approach this?
& 'C:\Program Files\Amazon\EC2Launch\EC2Launch.exe' sysprep --shutdown=false

